# snap install conjure-up --classic --beta failing

Tags: 16.04, snap, conjure-up

In Ubuntu 16.04, install is failing with the following message:

```
error: unknown flag 'classic'
```

Performing a `sudo snap install install conjure-up --beta` fails with the message:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Make snap "ubuntu-core" available to the system (no state entry for key)
- Mount snap "conjure-up" (snap "conjure-up" requires classic or confinement override)
```

Comment: sudo snap install conjure-up --beta --classic
error: unknown flag `classic'

Comment: sudo snap install conjure-up --beta
75.28 MB / 75.28 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 4.88 MB/s 

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Make snap "ubuntu-core" available to the system (no state entry for key)
- Mount snap "conjure-up" (snap "conjure-up" requires classic or confinement override)

Comment: Corrected unknown flag 'classic' error after executing the below:

Comment: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure you're running snapd version 2.21 or later. A simple

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Should correct this issue.